# Parallax Scrolling with Skrollr, How do I make a div slide over another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, skrollr

I want to mimic the effect used on http://laravel.com.

I've done a few Skrollr tutorials now, and I understand how to animate elements based on a keyframe, but I'm not sure how to replicate the effect used in my example. I can't even begin to work out what sort of transform this would be.

Could somebody help me to mimic this in jsfiddle or a similar tool?

Comment: Please read [ask] and try again

Comment: Not with Skrollr but this might help : http://jsfiddle.net/apederson/z93R7/